# jOOQ - parse plain sql with QueryPart placeholders

Tags: java, sql, parsing, jooq

I have a fields, that was created from from plain Sql string in MSSQL Dialect and that can't be feed to a parser due to a complex syntax. And i have a Plain sql string with query parts placeholders in PostgreSQL dialect, like so:

```
String myComplexSqlString = "({0} + sum({1}::integer)::text || {3}"
```

Is there any ways i can parse this SQL and insert all the query parts i need after the parsing step and render the whole field to MSSQL Dialect? Any suggestions?

Comment: Would love to discuss this use case more in detail if you're interested: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not currently possible but it does sound interesting. I've created a feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9447

For the time being, in your example, there's nothing preventing you from using jOOQ's API to construct this "complex SQL":

```
Field<String> complexSQL(Field<? extends Number> arg0, Field<?> arg1, Field<?> arg3) {
    return cast(arg0.add(sum(cast(arg1, INTEGER))), CLOB).concat(arg3);
}
```

Comment: I used this string just as an example. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @NikitaLygin: I'm always trying to write an answer for both you *and* every future reader of this question. I was sure that writing this expression using jOOQ API might not do the trick for you, but it might do the trick for someone else.